# Showing that $f(x)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} \sin |x|_2 \\ |x|_2^3+1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I want to show that $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2, f(x)=\begin{pmatrix} \sin |x|_2 \\ |x|_2^3+1 \end{pmatrix}$ is differentiable.

I believe I have to show that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both differentiable and their derivatives both continuous. Is it enough to say that $\partial _1 f_1=\cos |x|_2$ and $\partial _2 f_2 = 3|x|_2^2$ which are both continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I feel like this is not enough...

Comment: when you write $|x|_2$, do you mean the Euclidean norm $|x|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$? If yes, then first of all, you calculated the partial derivatives incorrectly. Second, you need to show that all the partial derivatives are continuous; i.e show that $\partial_1 f_1, \partial_2 f_1, \partial_3 f_1, \partial_1 f_2, \partial_2 f_2, \partial_3 f_2$ are all continuous functions on $\Bbb{R}^3 \setminus\{0\}$. (strictly speaking, you dont NEED to show this, but this provides a simple proof that $f$ is differentiable)

Comment: Yes, I missed that, sorry!

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to prove it?

Comment: actually, if you make the observation that the Euclidean norm is differentiable away from the origin, then this becomes an easy corollary of the chain rule (but to prove that the norm is diiferentiable, you might end up resorting to proving that all of its partial derivatives are continuous... there are other ways as well, again, making use of chain rule, but this is the most direct)

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Actually, by defining $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, you must show that the functions $\sin |x|_2=\sin\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ and $|x|_2^3+1=\left(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}\right)^3+1$ are differentiable w.r.t. $x_1,x_2,x_3$ by using partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Proving $|x|$ is differentiable on the given domain is simple: First, $p(x)=|x|^2$ is differentiable everywhere, being a simple polynomial. And the function $q(t)=\sqrt t$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty).$ Therefore on $R^3 \setminus \{0\},$ where $p>0,$   $|x|=q\circ p(x)$ is the composition of two differentiable maps, hence is differentiable.

The whole problem can be approached in this way, with no computations necessary.